# How do I make RecyclerView update its layout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with a bunch of custom views which may change height after a while, because they contain `ImageView`s which load their image asynchronously. The `RecyclerView` does not pick up on this layout change, although I call `forceLayout` on the `ImageView`, and the `RecyclerView` is initialized with `setHasFixedSize(false)`. All container-parents of the `ImageView` have set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

How can I make the `RecyclerView` update its layout? With good'ol `ListView` this was not a problem.

Comment: How do you load the image data? Is the asynchronous loading from a `Loader<D>`? From an `AsyncTask`? Is the data maintained in a `Cursor`? I'm asking to understand how you're maintaining data state.

Comment: I'm something similar to AsyncTask which has a callback (https://github.com/koush/ion). In the callback I've tried calling forceLayout

Comment: Bring your code here. How you set your adapter to the RecyclerView and where and on which thread you notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: I have the same issue with 23.1.0 support lib version. I just set a new layout manager on the recycler view.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google has finally fixed this in [support library v23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html). Issue is fixed by updating this line in `build.gradle` after updating your support repository with the SDK Manager:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

Comment: hey @Nilzor can please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952965/recyclerview-horizontal-scrolling-to-left

Answer (score 24):

You can use the `notifyDataSetChanged` in the `Adapter` for the `RecyclerView` if all your images change at the same time or `notifyItemChanged(int position)` if only one of the items has changed. This will tell the `RecyclerView` to rebind the particular `View`.

Comment: Watch out for this issue, as currently calling notifyDataSetChanged might throw an exception. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77846

Comment: This will update the entire recyclerview. If it uses up the entire screen on a tablet with images, that will result in a significant performance issue that will be noticeable to users. You should avoid updating the entire recyclerview when only a small section of the layout changes.

Answer (score 5):

Call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged(int position)` methods of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` from the **MAIN THREAD**. Calling it from an `AsyncTask` may result in the main thread not updating the `ImageView`s. Its most convenient to have a callback method in the activity/fragment work as a listener, and have it called by the `AsyncTask` in `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 2):

```
int wantedPosition = 25; // Whatever position you're looking for
int firstPosition = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(); // This is the same as child #0
int wantedChild = wantedPosition - firstPosition;

if (wantedChild < 0 || wantedChild >= linearLayoutManager.getChildCount()) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Unable to get view for desired position, because it's not being displayed on screen.");
    return;
}

View wantedView = linearLayoutManager.getChildAt(wantedChild);
mlayoutOver =(LinearLayout)wantedView.findViewById(R.id.layout_over);
mlayoutPopup = (LinearLayout)wantedView.findViewById(R.id.layout_popup);

mlayoutOver.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
mlayoutPopup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This code is worked for me.

Comment: This is not working for the child at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I just set a fix width and height for the ImageView. Try that and see where you get. You can also use a lib for this, I use Square Picasso and I got it working with RecyclerView.

Comment: Fixed with and height is not an option. The design requires height to be determined by the image height.