# onItemClickListeners misbehaving after RecyclerView resize

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a pinch-to-zoom RecyclerView and have the pinch-to-zoom functionality working, but once zoomed in, the onItemClickListeners are in the wrong locations. Below is the code for the modified RecyclerView. I also made a [simple demo that is hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/percula/RecyclerPinchZoom). When trying the demo, when you click on an item, you should get a Toast that says the number of the icon you click on. Try it without zooming, then zoom in and try again to see the issue. I believe that I need to notify the RecyclerView that the onItemClickListener locations need to be updated, but cannot find the correct method to override. Thanks for any help!

```
public class PinchRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;
    private float maxWidth = 0.0f;
    private float maxHeight = 0.0f;
    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    private float width;
    private float height;


    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    public PinchRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        if (!isInEditMode())
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        width = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        height = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        try {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
        super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = ev.getX();
                final float y = ev.getY();
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                        >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                if (mPosX > 0.0f)
                    mPosX = 0.0f;
                else if (mPosX < maxWidth)
                    mPosX = maxWidth;

                if (mPosY > 0.0f)
                    mPosY = 0.0f;
                else if (mPosY < maxHeight)
                    mPosY = maxHeight;

                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;

                invalidate();
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        if (mScaleFactor == 1.0f) {
            mPosX = 0.0f;
            mPosY = 0.0f;
        }
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        invalidate();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(1.0f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 3.0f));
            maxWidth = width - (width * mScaleFactor);
            maxHeight = height - (height * mScaleFactor);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

No Zoom, Clicked #34, Working
[image: No Zoom, Clicked #34, Working]

Zoomed In, Clicked #34, Not Working
[image: Zoomed In, Clicked #34, Not Working]

Comment: You are manipulating with `Canvas`. Instead, you have to work with the actual layout manager, thus **managing layout process**. Currently you are just *faking* just by performing changes to the canvas, but the layout beneath it is completely not touched. Imo, you have to subclass `GridLayoutManager` and perform the heavy lifting there.

Comment: Do you use recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true) ? If yes then remove that line and try

Comment: See my updated answer for a gist with a little cleaner implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**
I thought better of spreading the modifications throughout several of your classes. [Here](https://github.com/Cheticamp/RecyclerPinchZoom/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/perculacreative/peter/recyclerpinchzoom/PinchRecyclerView.java) is a link to just `PinchRecyclerView.java` with all the changes that are needed. I will leave the entire project linked below in case there is some other use for it.

---

You are changing just the display on the canvas and not the underlying views as azizbekian stated in his comment. If you don't want to go with a custom `GridLayoutManager` and continue with the approach you have embarked upon, you will need to map screen touches back to your underlying views.

Here is your [updated project](https://github.com/Cheticamp/RecyclerPinchZoom) on GitHub that does the mapping. Here are the basic changes:

- Add a touch listener to the `PinchRecyclerView`.
- Translate touch coordinates on the `PinchRecyclerView` to the corresponding position within your underlying layout.
- Identify through searching the intended item view and do your click processing.

<s>If you try this updated app and, as you can see in the video, the touch listener is also triggered on a pinch, so that is a bug.</s>

[image: Video]

Comment: Thank you @Cheticamp! It seems the key was adding an onTouchListener within the adapter. Your modifications work flawlessly.

Comment: Sorry to bring this up, @Cheticamp, I tried your code, but I am wondering why it keeps getting the selected item to the next item? For example I clicked on 38, and toast message display I clicked on 39? I have two additional views on left and right sides of recyclerview. Please help.

Comment: Thanks @Cheticamp, It is working fine for the item click, but it fails in case of row_item child click listener, If we have set the any onClickListener for any child of row_item then after scrolling or zoom in/out, it doesn't work,

when we show screen first time it works as expected, but after scroll and/or zoom in/out, it doesn't work, any solution for this please ?

Comment: Also when we zoom the recyclerView the text we set are looks blur, is any solutions for that ?

Comment: Hello @Cheticamp, It would be very thankful if you have solution for above two bugs.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Oops. The links are reestablished.

Comment: zooming functionality is working smooth. But click listener not working when it is zoom

Answer (score 0):

Here is an architecture of how the recyclerview works

**Adapter supplies data to >  ViewHolder**

ViewHolder stores the data items findviewbyid's in memory/saved location to prevent finding views every time you scroll for performance issues. Next...its

**ViewHolder > LayoutManager**

Layout manager stores the position of each item and does the job of updating their positions on pinch to zoom, scroll etc.

I think the way to solve this issue is to try and call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Inside a method that returns true when zoom activity is detected. Do not do this in adaper class do it in zoom activity class.

This should update the LayoutManager/ViewHolder and reassign ids.

Or

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
```

To tell that item range has been changed

You can see more on this
[How to update RecyclerView Adapter Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data)

[How do I make RecyclerView update its layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306870/how-do-i-make-recyclerview-update-its-layout)

**Both Answered**

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work. NotifyDataSetChanged() refers to the data set that the adapter uses to populates the views but does not affect layouts in any way. Just to be sure, I tried it and it did not work, as expected. Thanks though.

Comment: If I do understand you well, do you mean that onclick listener only gets item id correctly when in normal size without zoom but returns wrong item id/object when zoom is used? I cant use my computer right now pls can you post a screenshot of the problem

Comment: That is correct. Please see my edited question with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add the click listeners in your `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(...);
```

And as azizbekian already stated, use your own `LayoutManager` for the layout.