# Recycleview updates its layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

My question is asked before in many threads such as 
[How do I make RecyclerView update its layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306870/how-do-i-make-recyclerview-update-its-layout).
But unfortunately none of them fixed my issue.
I am using recycleview in my android project. for each item I have hidden checkbox and I am trying to make it visible for all items when long pressing. I am trying to call: adapter.notifyItemChanged() in such case but for nothing. sometimes It updates and sometimes does not and in case of updating it updadtes some items and left others.
Here is my code:

```
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            CheckBox checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        }
        }));
        and my listener class is:

public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    void onItemLongClick(View view, int position);
}

private OnItemClickListener mListener;

private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View childView = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

            if (childView != null && mListener != null) {
                mListener.onItemLongClick(childView, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {
}
```

}

Comment: show some part of the code...

Comment: Your answer is right there the link you have added . Post your code if you need any help .

Comment: I could not understand why some guys dislike and downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by adding a boolean flag in the adapter. Then, In the method onBindViewHolder I check this flag and depending on it I show or hide Items' checkboxes as following:

```
    if(flag){
        holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Finally in the long click method I set that flag and call notifyDataSetChanged method to update RecycleView's layout as following:

```
    adapter.flag = true;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```